# How to remove identical lines in one file from another, using sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have two files, one being a superset of the other.  I want to remove the identical lines in the smaller files from the larger file.

One possible complication is that the lines contain backslashes.

How do I do this?

Comment: You (or someone) may be able to leverage some [similar code I wrote](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257913/135943), which uses `sed` to strip out all copies of the first line from a file (but leaves the first line in place).

Answer (score 8):

Here is my snippet:

```
remove_lines()
{
    # remove lines from a file 
    #  
    # $1 - source file with patterns of lines to be removed
    # $2 - destination file
    tmpfile=$(mktemp "$(dirname -- "$2")"/XXXXXXXX) &&
    grep -F -f "$1" -v -- "$2" >>"$tmpfile" &&
    mv -- "$tmpfile" "$2" &&
}
```

EDIT: I've just realized that there is no `sed` in it, but that wasn't critical, was it?

Comment: You might want to use `mktemp` for generating the temporary file name, instead of `tmp-$(uuidgen)` or similar hacks.

Comment: OP presupposed that sed was necessary, but didn't specify why another solution would be unacceptable. +1.

Comment: I used the line in your script like so:

    `grep -F -f "uniq_failing_specs.txt" -v -- "all_specs.txt" >>"passing_specs.txt"`

Comment: @ThomasDickey's point in [his answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/263430/135943) is correct; by not using `-x` you open this up to unexpected behavior due to flawed logic.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following script;

```
## $1 - Small File
## $2 - Large File

sed 's/^/\//; s/$/\/d/; s/\\/\\\\/g' $1 > $HOME/sed_scpt.txt
sed 's/\\/\\\\/g' $2 | sed -f $HOME/sed_scpt.txt > $HOME/desired_output.txt

## Alternatively, you could change the 2nd line with the following;
sed -f $HOME/sed_scpt.txt $2 > $HOME/desired_output.txt
```

NOTE: I've used GNU sed 4.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @rajish using `grep` was close, but overlooked something: the question asked about removing identical *lines*.  By default, `grep` will match *strings* (parts of lines).

[POSIX grep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) has a suitable option:

> **`-x`**
>       Consider only input lines that use all characters in the line excluding the terminating *newline* to match an entire fixed string or regular expression to be matching lines.

Given that, one could use `grep` to do this:

```
cp -f -p input.txt input.txt~
grep -v -x -F -f input.pat input.txt~ >input.txt
```

where *input.pat* contains the lines to be removed, and *input.txt* is the file to be updated.

The solution by @nvarun *using* `sed` had a similar problem, in addition to not escaping `/` characters in the pattern file.  This example works for me, and limits the syntax to [POSIX sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html):

```
cp -f -p input.txt input.txt~
sed -e 's/\([\/]\)/\\\1/g' -e 's/^/\/^/' -e 's/$/$\/d/' input.pat > input.sed
sed -f input.sed input.txt~ >input.txt
```

Just to be tidy, both save the original file before updating it ([POSIX cp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html)).

*input.pat*

```
first
this is second
second/third
second\third
```

*input.txt*

```
first
only first should match
this is not first
this is second
the previous line said this is second
first/second/third
second/third
first\second\third
second\third
```

Result:

```
only first should match
this is not first
the previous line said this is second
first/second/third
first\second\third
```