# Remove extra header lines from file, except for the first line

Tags: text-processing

I have a file that looks like this toy example.  My actual file has 4 million lines, about 10 of which I need to delete.

```
ID  Data1  Data2
1    100    100
2    100    200
3    200    100
ID  Data1  Data2
4    100    100
ID  Data1  Data2
5    200    200
```

I want to delete the lines that look like the header, except for the first line.

Final file:

```
ID  Data1  Data2
1    100    100
2    100    200
3    200    100
4    100    100
5    200    200
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
header=$(head -n 1 input)
(printf "%s\n" "$header";
 grep -vFxe "$header" input
) > output
```

1. grab the header line from the input file into a variable
2. print the header
3. process the file with `grep` to omit lines that match the header
4. capture the output from the above two steps into the output file

Comment: or perhaps `{ IFS= read -r head; printf '%s\n' "$head"; grep -vF "$head" ; } <file`

Comment: Both good additions. Thanks to don_crissti for indirectly pointing out that posix recently removed -1 syntax from head, in favor of -n 1.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, _recently_ as in 12 years ago. And `head -1` has been obsoleted for decades before that.

Answer (score 39):

You can use

```
sed '2,${/ID/d;}'
```

This will delete lines with ID starting from line 2.

Comment: nice; or to be more specific with the pattern matching, `sed '2,${/^ID  Data1  Data2$/d;}' file` (using the right number of spaces between the columns, of course)

Comment: Hm I thought you could omit the semicolon for only 1 command, but ok.

Comment: Not w/ sane `sed`s, no.

Comment: aaaand -i for the in-place edit win.

Comment: Or `sed '1!{/ID/d;}'`

Answer (score 10):

For those who do not like curly brackets

```
sed -e '1n' -e '/^ID/d'
```

- `n` means `pass` line No.`1`
- `d` delete all matched line(s) that start with `^ID`

Comment: This can also be shorten to `sed '1n;/^ID/d'` filename. just a suggestion

Comment: Note that this will also print lines like `IDfoo` which are not the same as the header (unlikely to make a difference in this case, but you never know).

Answer (score 6):

Here's a fun one.  You can use `sed` directly to strip all copies of the first line out and leave everything else in place (including the first line itself).

```
sed '1{h;n;};G;/^\(.*\)\n\1$/d;s/\n.*$//' input
```

`1{h;n;}` puts the first line into the hold space, prints it, and reads in the next line—skipping the rest of the `sed` commands for the first line.  (It also [skips that first `1` test for the second line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294517/what-is-the-difference-between-the-sed-commands-n-and-b#comment674188_294526), but that doesn't matter as that test wouldn't have applied to the second line.)

`G` appends a newline followed by the contents of the hold space to the pattern space.

`/^\(.*\)\n\1$/d` deletes the contents of the pattern space (thus skipping to the next line) if the portion after the newline (i.e. what was appended from the hold space) exactly matches the portion before the newline.  This is where lines that duplicate the header will get deleted.

`s/\n.*$//` deletes the portion of text that was added by the `G` command, so that what gets printed is just the line of text from the file.

However, since regex is expensive, a slightly faster approach would be to use the same condition (negated) and `P`rint up to the newline if the portion after the newline (i.e. what was appended from the hold space) *doesn't* exactly match the portion before the newline and then unconditionally delete the pattern space:

```
sed '1{h;n;};G;/^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P;d' input
```

Output when given your input is:

```
ID  Data1  Data2
1    100    100
2    100    200
3    200    100
4    100    100
5    200    200
```

Comment: Related: http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6269/4676

Comment: @don_crissti, interesting addition; thanks!  I would probably opt for the longer but equivalent `sed '1{h;n;};G;/^\(.*\)\n\1$/d;P;d' input`; somehow it's easier for me to read.  :)

Comment: Also related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/417736/135943

Answer (score 6):

Here are a couple more choices that don't require you to know the first line in advance:

```
perl -ne 'print unless $_ eq $k; $k=$_ if $.==1;
```

The `-n` flag tells perl to loop over its input file, saving each line as `$_`. The `$k=$_ if $.==1;` saves the first line (`$.` is the line number, so `$.==1` will only be true for the 1st line) as `$k`. The `print unless $k eq $_` prints the current line if it isn't the same as the one saved in `$k`.

Alternatively, the same thing in `awk`:

```
awk '$0!=x;(NR==1){x=$0}' file
```

Here, we test whether the current line is the same as what is saved in the variable `x`. If the test `$0!=x` evaluates to true (if the current line `$0` is not the same as `x`), the line will be printed because the default action for awk on true expressions is to print. The first line (`NR==1`) is saved as `x`. Since this is done after checking whether the current line matches `x`, this ensures that the first line will also be printed.

Comment: I like not having to know the first line idea since it makes it a generalized script for your toolbox.

Comment: that awk method creates an empty/false array entry per distinct line; for 4M lines 
if all different (not clear from Q) and fairly short (appears so) this is probably okay, but if 
there are much more or longer lines this could thrash or die. `!($0 in a)` tests without creating and avoids this, or awk can do 
the same logic as you have for perl: `'$0!=x; NR==1{x=$0}'` or if the header line can be empty `'NR==1{x=$0;print} $0!=x'`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 where is an array per line created? You mean `!a[$0]`? Why would that create an entry in `a`?

Comment: Because that's how awk works; see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Reference-to-Elements.html#Reference-to-Elements especially the "NOTE".

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 well I'll be damned! Thanks, I was not aware of that. Fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

AWK is a quite decent tool for such purpose as well. Here's sample run of code:

```
$ awk 'NR == 1 {print} NR != 1 && $0!~/ID  Data1  Data2/' rmLines.txt | head -n 10                                
ID  Data1  Data2
1    100    100
     100    200
3    200    100
1    100    100
     100    200
3    200    100
1    100    100
     100    200
3    200    100
```

**Break down**:

- `NR == 1 {print}` tells us to print first line of text file
- `NR != 1 && $0!~/ID  Data1  Data2/`  logical operator `&&` tells AWK to print line that is not equal to 1 and doesn't contain `ID Data1 Data2`. Note the lack of `{print}` part; in awk if a test condition is evaluated to true,it is assumed for line to be printed.
- `| head -n 10` is just a tiny addition to limit output to only first 10 lines. Not relevant to the `AWK` part itself, only used for demo purpose.

If you want that in a file, redirect the output of the command by appending `> newFile.txt` at the end of command, like so:

```
awk 'NR == 1 {print} NR != 1 && $0!~/ID  Data1  Data2/' rmLines.txt > newFile.txt
```

How does it hold up ? Pretty good actually:

```
$ time awk 'NR == 1 {print} NR != 1 && $0!~/ID  Data1  Data2/' rmLines.txt > /dev/null                            
    0m3.60s real     0m3.53s user     0m0.06s system
```

**Side note**

The generated sample file was done with  for looping from one to million and printing first four lines of your file (so 4 lines times million equals 4 millions of lines ), which took 0.09 seconds, by the way.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ for(i=1;i<=1000000;i++) printf("ID  Data1  Data2\n1    100    100\n     100    200\n3    200    100\n");  }' > rmLines.txt
```

Comment: Note that this will also print lines like `ID  Data1  Data2 foo` which are not the same as the header (unlikely to make a difference in this case, but you never know).

Comment: @terdon yes, exactly right. OP however specified only one pattern they want to remove and his example appears to support that

Answer (score 4):

Awk, adapting to any header automatically:

```
awk '( FNR == 1) {header=$0;print $0;}
     ( FNR > 1) && ($0 != header) { print $0;}'  file1  file2 ....
```

ie, on the first line, get the header and print it, and subsequent line DIFFERENT from that header get printed.

FNR = Number of Records in the current File, so that you can have multiple files and it will do the same in each of them.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, Perl solution IMO slightly more elegant than @terdon gave:

```
perl -i -p -e 's/^ID.*$//s if $. > 1' file
```

Comment: Ah, but the whole point of mine was to avoid the need to specify the pattern and instead read it from the first line. Your approach will simply delete any line that starts with `ID`. You have no guarantee that this won't delete lines that should be kept. Since you brought up elegance, `g` is pointless if you use `^` and `$`. In fact, all of your options to `m///` are useless here except `s`; they activate features you're not using. So's the `$`, `s/^ID.*//s` would do the same thing.

Comment: @terdon, fair enough. Yours is much more universal!

Answer (score 3):

Just to push back on the question a little bit ... it looks like maybe your input is itself the result of catting several TSV files together. If you can back up a step in your processing pipeline (if you own that or can talk to the people who do) you could use a header-aware tool to concatenate the data in the first place, and thereby remove the problem of having to remove extra header lines.

For example, using [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/tree/v4.5.0):

```
$ cat f1.tsv
ID  Data1 Data2
1 100 100
2 100 200
3 200 100
$ cat f2.tsv
ID  Data1 Data2
4 100 100
$ cat f3.tsv
ID  Data1 Data2
5 200 200

$ cat f1.tsv f2.tsv  f3.tsv
ID  Data1 Data2
1 100 100
2 100 200
3 200 100
ID  Data1 Data2
4 100 100
ID  Data1 Data2
5 200 200

$ mlr --tsvlite cat f1.tsv f2.tsv  f3.tsv
ID  Data1 Data2
1 100 100
2 100 200
3 200 100
4 100 100
5 200 200
```

Comment: Thank you for adding this tidbit.  This will be extremely useful in the future, as most of my pipelines require joining and merging files from individual samples.

Comment: That's good advice and you can do the same thing using any awk in any shell on every Unix box by just writing `awk 'NR==1 || FNR>1' *.tsv`

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'NR==1{h=$0; print} $0!=h' file
ID  Data1  Data2
1    100    100
2    100    200
3    200    100
4    100    100
5    200    200
```

Comment: this is a great solution in its simplicity. thank god for awk