# Don't understand the 'n' command of sed

Tags: sed

I'm reading `sed & awk` book and I thought that I understood the `n` command of `sed` till I executed the following:

```
$ echo -ne "abc\ncde\nfg\n" | sed "/c/{
n
/f/d
}"
```

Output:

```
abc
cde
fg
```

But I expected the line `fg` to be deleted.

My understanding of the process:

- `c` matches the line `cde`, the next line is `fg` and should be deleted by the `/f/d` command as it is matched by `f`.

I was so sure that I understand this command and it is simple. Especially because the authors write that the uppercase commands `N,D,P` commands are more difficult and if you understand them then you understand the lowercase commands anyway. But I have no difficulties with the `N` command at all.

Comment: Think what you wanted was `sed '/c/{N;P;/f/!{D};d}'`.

Comment: As I said [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/294517) `n` doesn't return to the top of the script (i.e. it doesn't restart the command cycle), it just runs the remaining commands (so the conditional block `/c/{..}` is never applied to the `cde` line); and just for fun: edit the last line to read `cfg` and you'll see it won't be deleted, even if it does match `/c/` and `/f/`

Comment: I think you script says delete any record with an `f` in it that follows an odd number of records with a `c` in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the comment of @don_crissti I think I understand how `n` command affects flow control of `sed`.

`n` excludes the read (or next) line from the analysis `..."/c/{...` in the next cycle. So if use `n` 2 times in my example, `abc` will be matched then `cde` will be read, then `fg` will be read and deleted.

```
$ echo -ne "abc\ncde\nfg\n" | sed "/c/{
n
n
/f/d
}"
```

Output:

```
abc
cde
```

Comment: No, `n` does not exclude anything. It outputs the current line (unless `-n` is used) and reads the next line. The second `n` outputs the second line and reads the `fg` line. Then the `/f/` matches and the `d` deletes.

Comment: @Kusalananda - you misread the post here... _`n`  "excludes" the commands that precede it from being applied to the line that was just pulled in_ because it doesn't return to the top of the script. _ka3ak_ phrasing is far from ideal but the message is quite clear (at least to me).

Comment: @don_crissti Ah, well, yes, that's a "feature" of `n` in a way, at least in this case.

Comment: @Kusalananda - absolutely, it's actually _the_ feature that trips most people up.

Comment: "top of the script" is also mentioned in the book but I couldn't understand what it means. All I wanted to say is that you have to do something with the line returned by 'n' between 'n' and closing curly brace because the next cycle (..."/c/{...) will skip it.

Answer (score 6):

The problem, your line `fg` is never matched by the pattern `/f/`.

The first line `abc` matched `/c/`, then the commands inside block are executed.

- The `n` command print the current pattern space, which is `abc` and replace the pattern space with next line of input, which is `cde`.
- `cde` doesn't match `/f/`, then it was not `d`eleted, and printed to standard out.

Now, next line of input is `fg` was read, doesn't match `/c/`, then the code block was not executed.

You can verify by using `l`ook command:

```
echo -ne "abc\ncde\nfg\n" | sed -n "l;/c/{
n
/f/d
}"
```

outputs:

```
abc$
fg$
```

Adding `l`ook command at the beginning of script tells you which lines of input was processed outside of code block.

Comment: @WouterVerhelst: Ah, right, it's typo, thanks.