# awk + append lines before captured word only if lines are not defined in the file

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, logs

The following `awk` syntax will add the 3 lines in the file before the line with the word - 'DatePattern':

```
$ awk 'done != 1 && /DatePattern/ {
    print "log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender"
    print "log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex=100"
    print "log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxFileSize=10MB"
    done = 1
    } 1' file >newfile && mv newfile file
```

the problem is that `awk` does not care if the lines already exist, so what needs to be added to the `awk`, in order to insert the lines only if lines are not already present?

#### Other example

In this case we want to add before the line with word 'HOTEL' the names 'trump', 'bush', & 'putin', but only in the case where the names do not exists:

```
$ awk 'done != 1 && /HOTEL/ {
    print "trump"
    print "bush"
    print "putin"
    done = 1
    } 1' file >newfile && mv newfile file
```

Comment: Something like     perl -pi -e 's/(?!putin\n)(HOTEL)/$1trump\nbush\nputin$2/g' file

Comment: I've seen this question surface a number of times.  I wrote a fully POSIX compliant answer to it on the vi/Vim stack exchange: [How to append some line at the end of the file only if it's not there yet?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6248/4676)

Comment: Also related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6269/4676 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257913/135943

Comment: Exists none of the names? Any constraints on the names' order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this as follows:

```
# store the 3 lines to match in shell variables
line_1="log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender"
line_2="log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex=100"
line_3="log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxFileSize=10MB"

# function that escapes it's first argument to make it palatable
# for use in `sed` editor's `s///` command's left-hand side argument
esc() {
    printf '%s\n' "$1" | sed -e 's:[][\/.^$*]:\\&:g'
}

# escape the lines
line_1_esc=$(esc "$line_1")
line_2_esc=$(esc "$line_2")
line_3_esc=$(esc "$line_3")

# invoke `sed` and fill up the pattern space with 4 lines (rather than the default 1)
# then apply the regex to detect the presence of the lines 1/2/3.
sed -e '
    1N;2N;$!N
    '"/^$line_1_esc\n$line_2_esc\n$line_3_esc\n.*DatePattern/"'!D
    :a;n;$!ba
' input.file
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption that the order of the names doesn't matter, and they would occur always in a pack of three, try

```
awk '
BEGIN           {INSTXT = "trump" ORS "bush" ORS "putin"
                 for (n = split (INSTXT, T, ORS); n; n--) PRES[T[n]]
                }

!(LAST in PRES) &&
/HOTEL/         {print INSTXT
                }

                {LAST = $0
                }
1
' file
```