# AWK: how can I remove repeated header lines from CSV?

Tags: awk

Dealing with the csv produced by the concatenation of several CSVs, I am looking for the possibility to remove repeats of the header lines (present in the each concatunated CSV being identical among them). here is my CSV contained repeats of the first line:

```
ID(Prot),   ID(lig),    ID(cluster),    dG(rescored),   dG(before), POP(before)
1000,   lig40,  1,  0.805136,   -5.5200,    79
1000,   lig868, 1,  0.933209,   -5.6100,    42
1000,   lig278, 1,  0.933689,   -5.7600,    40
1000,   lig619, 3,  0.946354,   -7.6100,    20
1000,   lig211, 1,  0.960048,   -5.2800,    39
1000,   lig40,  2,  0.971051,   -4.9900,    40
1000,   lig868, 3,  0.986384,   -5.5000,    29
1000,   lig12,  3,  0.988506,   -6.7100,    16
1000,   lig800, 16, 0.995574,   -4.5300,    40
1000,   lig800, 1,  0.999935,   -5.7900,    22
1000,   lig619, 1,  1.00876,    -7.9000,    3
1000,   lig619, 2,  1.02254,    -7.6400,    1
1000,   lig12,  1,  1.02723,    -6.8600,    5
1000,   lig12,  2,  1.03273,    -6.8100,    4
1000,   lig211, 2,  1.03722,    -5.2000,    19
1000,   lig211, 3,  1.03738,    -5.0400,    21
ID(Prot),   ID(lig),    ID(cluster),    dG(rescored),   dG(before), POP(before)
10V1,   lig40,  1,  0.513472,   -6.4600,    150
10V1,   lig211, 2,  0.695981,   -6.8200,    91
10V1,   lig278, 1,  0.764432,   -7.0900,    70
10V1,   lig868, 1,  0.787698,   -7.3100,    62
10V1,   lig211, 1,  0.83416,    -6.8800,    54
10V1,   lig868, 3,  0.888408,   -6.4700,    44
10V1,   lig278, 2,  0.915932,   -6.6600,    35
10V1,   lig12,  1,  0.922741,   -9.3600,    19
10V1,   lig12,  8,  0.934144,   -7.4600,    24
10V1,   lig40,  2,  0.949955,   -5.9000,    34
10V1,   lig800, 5,  0.964194,   -5.9200,    30
10V1,   lig868, 2,  0.966243,   -6.9100,    20
10V1,   lig12,  2,  0.972575,   -8.3000,    10
10V1,   lig619, 6,  0.979168,   -8.1600,    9
10V1,   lig619, 4,  0.986202,   -8.7800,    5
10V1,   lig800, 2,  0.989599,   -6.2400,    20
10V1,   lig619, 1,  0.989725,   -9.2900,    3
10V1,   lig12,  7,  0.991535,   -7.5800,    9
ID(Prot),   ID(lig),    ID(cluster),    dG(rescored),   dG(before), POP(before)
10V2,   lig40,  1,  0.525767,   -6.4600,    146
10V2,   lig211, 2,  0.744702,   -6.8200,    78
10V2,   lig278, 1,  0.749015,   -7.0900,    74
10V2,   lig868, 1,  0.772025,   -7.3100,    66
10V2,   lig211, 1,  0.799829,   -6.8700,    63
10V2,   lig12,  1,  0.899345,   -9.1600,    25
10V2,   lig12,  4,  0.899606,   -7.5500,    32
10V2,   lig868, 3,  0.903364,   -6.4800,    40
10V2,   lig278, 3,  0.913145,   -6.6300,    36
10V2,   lig800, 5,  0.94576,    -5.9100,    35
```

To post-process this CSV I need to remove repetitions of the header line

```
ID(Prot),   ID(lig),    ID(cluster),    dG(rescored),   dG(before), POP(before)
```

keeping the header only in the begining of the fused csv (on the first line!).I have tried to use the following awk one-liner which is looking for the 1st line and then remove its repeates

```
 awk '{first=$1;gsub("ID(Prot)","");print first,$0}' mycsv.csv > csv_without_repeats.csv
```

however it did not recognize the header line, meaning that the pattern was not defined correctly.

How my AWK code could be corrected supposed that further it should be piped to sort in other to sort the lines after the filtering of the repeats ?

```
awk '{first=$1;gsub(/ID(Prot)?(\([-azA-Z]+\))?/,"");print first,$0}' | LC_ALL=C sort -k4,4g input.csv > sorted_and_without_repeats.csv
```

Comment: Obvious suggestion - don't concatenate the CSVs in the first place.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/257819/117549

Comment: By the way, please stop posting large amounts of sample input/output when it takes a fraction of that to demonstrate your problem. Any time we need a scroll bar to see your sample input or output it's much too big.

Comment: @EdMorton. Or at least run all but the first file through `tail -n +2` to skip the first row (or all files and add the first row of any file at the beginning with `head -n 1`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an `awk` script that will skip any lines that start with `ID(Prot)`, unless it is the first line:

```
awk 'NR==1 || !/^ID\(Prot\)/' file > newFile
```

Here's the same idea in `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'print if $.==1 || !/^ID\(Prot\)/' file > newFile
```

Or, to edit the original file in place:

```
perl -i -ne 'print if $.==1 || !/^ID\(Prot\)/' file
```

Comment: thank you ! may you specify how it would be possible to pipe your AWK sollution to sort in order to sort the data based on the values in the 4th column for example? I've tried awk 'NR==1 || !/^ID\(Prot\)/' | LC_ALL=C sort -k4,4g input.csv > output.csv but it did not work:-)

Comment: @HotJAMS you need to give an input file to `awk`, otherwise it doesn't have anything to work on. Just try `awk 'NR==1 || !/^ID(Prot)/' input.csv | LC_ALL=C sort -k4,4g > output.csv`

Comment: Fantastics! thank you very much again! chears

Comment: That pipe to sort relies on specific values in the header coming first in the sort vs the values in the same column in the rest of the file so it's probably OK for the OPs sample input but I wouldn't rely on it in general. It can also shuffle the order of the lines for the same 4th field values which may not be desirable. @HotJams please don't ask multiple questions in one SE question - keep each SE question focused and simple just ask a second question if you have one. That particular "sort with a header" question has been asked and answered many times on SE and SO though,

Answer (score 10):

With a POSIX-compliant `sed` (tested on `GNU sed` and  `busybox sed`):

```
sed '1!{/^ID/d;}' data
```

Delete all line, except the first, when this starts with `ID`. Some `sed` implementations have the `-i` option to enable editing the file in place.

---

`awk`:

```
awk 'NR == 1 {h=$0; print} $0 == h {next}1' data
```

If we are in the first line save the header and print it, then for each line we process if this is equal to the header skip it, otherwise print it.

---

Or the same in `perl`:

```
perl -lne '$h = $_ if $. == 1; print if($_ ne $h || $. == 1)' data
```

Add the `-i` option to let `perl` edit the file in place.

Comment: +1. And may be shortened to `awk 'NR==1{h=$0; print}; ($0 != h) ' input`.

Comment: @PrabhjotSingh original, you should post it as an ansers

Comment: Thanks for the sed line. It's simple enough that I could get it to work first time on a table where the undesirable rows each began with a different word (the month). I'm not familiar enough with awk or perl to do that.

Answer (score 7):

Here is one simple way to deal with the pbm using the `awk` utility. But be aware that even if an less/more space is prsent
in the headers then they would be included in the output.

```
awk '
  NR>1&&$0==hdr{next}
  NR==1{hdr=$0}1
' file
```

---

The same approach but in the stream editor utility sed:

```
sed -En '
  1h;1!G;/^(.*)\n\1$/!P
' file
```

Answer (score 7):

```bsh
grep -v -F -x -f <( head -n 1 file.csv | tee file-new.csv ) file.csv >>file-new.csv
```

This is using a shell that has process substitutions (`<(...)`), like `bash` or `zsh`, to get the header line from the file using `head`, write that to a new file with `tee`, and then filter out all  header lines from the original file using `grep`.  The filtered lines are appended to the new file, after the header which was previously written there by `tee`.

This way of doing it does not depend on what the header actually *is*.  It's just extracting all lines from the original file that happen to be different from the first line of the file.

Without the process substitution:

```bsh
head -n 1 file.csv | tee file-new.csv |
grep -v -F -x -f /dev/stdin file.csv >>file-new.csv
```

Comment: Can we use `-f -` instead of `-f /dev/stdin`?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You can with GNU `grep`, but not with the `grep` implementations found on some non-GNU systems (e.g. macOS and the other BSD systems).  The [POSIX standard for `grep`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) does not mention this as a possible special value for `-f`. I'm showing the more portable variation in my answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
$ awk 'NR==1{h=$0; print} $0!=h' file
ID(Prot),   ID(lig),    ID(cluster),    dG(rescored),   dG(before), POP(before)
1000,   lig40,  1,  0.805136,   -5.5200,    79
1000,   lig868, 1,  0.933209,   -5.6100,    42
1000,   lig278, 1,  0.933689,   -5.7600,    40
1000,   lig619, 3,  0.946354,   -7.6100,    20
1000,   lig211, 1,  0.960048,   -5.2800,    39
1000,   lig40,  2,  0.971051,   -4.9900,    40
1000,   lig868, 3,  0.986384,   -5.5000,    29
1000,   lig12,  3,  0.988506,   -6.7100,    16
1000,   lig800, 16, 0.995574,   -4.5300,    40
1000,   lig800, 1,  0.999935,   -5.7900,    22
1000,   lig619, 1,  1.00876,    -7.9000,    3
1000,   lig619, 2,  1.02254,    -7.6400,    1
1000,   lig12,  1,  1.02723,    -6.8600,    5
1000,   lig12,  2,  1.03273,    -6.8100,    4
1000,   lig211, 2,  1.03722,    -5.2000,    19
1000,   lig211, 3,  1.03738,    -5.0400,    21
10V1,   lig40,  1,  0.513472,   -6.4600,    150
10V1,   lig211, 2,  0.695981,   -6.8200,    91
10V1,   lig278, 1,  0.764432,   -7.0900,    70
10V1,   lig868, 1,  0.787698,   -7.3100,    62
10V1,   lig211, 1,  0.83416,    -6.8800,    54
10V1,   lig868, 3,  0.888408,   -6.4700,    44
10V1,   lig278, 2,  0.915932,   -6.6600,    35
10V1,   lig12,  1,  0.922741,   -9.3600,    19
10V1,   lig12,  8,  0.934144,   -7.4600,    24
10V1,   lig40,  2,  0.949955,   -5.9000,    34
10V1,   lig800, 5,  0.964194,   -5.9200,    30
10V1,   lig868, 2,  0.966243,   -6.9100,    20
10V1,   lig12,  2,  0.972575,   -8.3000,    10
10V1,   lig619, 6,  0.979168,   -8.1600,    9
10V1,   lig619, 4,  0.986202,   -8.7800,    5
10V1,   lig800, 2,  0.989599,   -6.2400,    20
10V1,   lig619, 1,  0.989725,   -9.2900,    3
10V1,   lig12,  7,  0.991535,   -7.5800,    9
10V2,   lig40,  1,  0.525767,   -6.4600,    146
10V2,   lig211, 2,  0.744702,   -6.8200,    78
10V2,   lig278, 1,  0.749015,   -7.0900,    74
10V2,   lig868, 1,  0.772025,   -7.3100,    66
10V2,   lig211, 1,  0.799829,   -6.8700,    63
10V2,   lig12,  1,  0.899345,   -9.1600,    25
10V2,   lig12,  4,  0.899606,   -7.5500,    32
10V2,   lig868, 3,  0.903364,   -6.4800,    40
10V2,   lig278, 3,  0.913145,   -6.6300,    36
10V2,   lig800, 5,  0.94576,    -5.9100,    35
```

Comment: +1 for being the most succinct.

Comment: @αғsнιη I don't like using `!h` instead of `NR==1` since what I'm really trying to do is capture the first line of the input, not the most recent line where `h` is false even if that does happen to almost certainly be true for only the first line of input in this case, and so `NR==1` is the clearest way to express that condition. `$0!=h; NR==1{h=$0}` would be fine though.

Answer (score 2):

This awk command should work whatever the header is. It saves the first line as the header, and only prints the following lines if they are different from the saved header. It will work as long as the repeating headers are strictly the same.

`awk 'NR==1 && header=$0; $0!=header' originalfile > newfile`

Comment: Note that this will omit printing the header if it is empty or can be parsed as the number 0. While not an issue in this case (given the Q), this seems to be an unwanted side effect (and this is why I feel it's worth pointing it out) and it may be relevant to readers dealing with a similar problem/different data.

Comment: @fra-san you are absolutely right. Given the circumstances of the question, one should only use this code, and mostly all the other answers, if appending different CSV files with their headers.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `grep` after having skipped the first line:

```
{
  head -n1
  grep -v '^ID'
} < file.csv
```

That assumes `file.csv` is a *regular* file (won't work with a pipe with most `head` implementation) and that `head` is POSIX compliant in that it will leave the cursor in stdin just after the first line.

To skip all lines that are identical to the first one, you could do:

```
{
  IFS= read -r header       &&
    printf '%s\n' "$header" &&
    grep -Fxe "$header"
} < file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk '{if(!seen[$0]++)print $0}' filename
```

output

```
ID(Prot),   ID(lig),    ID(cluster),    dG(rescored),   dG(before), POP(before)
1000,   lig40,  1,  0.805136,   -5.5200,    79
1000,   lig868, 1,  0.933209,   -5.6100,    42
1000,   lig278, 1,  0.933689,   -5.7600,    40
1000,   lig619, 3,  0.946354,   -7.6100,    20
1000,   lig211, 1,  0.960048,   -5.2800,    39
1000,   lig40,  2,  0.971051,   -4.9900,    40
1000,   lig868, 3,  0.986384,   -5.5000,    29
1000,   lig12,  3,  0.988506,   -6.7100,    16
1000,   lig800, 16, 0.995574,   -4.5300,    40
1000,   lig800, 1,  0.999935,   -5.7900,    22
1000,   lig619, 1,  1.00876,    -7.9000,    3
1000,   lig619, 2,  1.02254,    -7.6400,    1
1000,   lig12,  1,  1.02723,    -6.8600,    5
1000,   lig12,  2,  1.03273,    -6.8100,    4
1000,   lig211, 2,  1.03722,    -5.2000,    19
1000,   lig211, 3,  1.03738,    -5.0400,    21
10V1,   lig40,  1,  0.513472,   -6.4600,    150
10V1,   lig211, 2,  0.695981,   -6.8200,    91
10V1,   lig278, 1,  0.764432,   -7.0900,    70
10V1,   lig868, 1,  0.787698,   -7.3100,    62
10V1,   lig211, 1,  0.83416,    -6.8800,    54
10V1,   lig868, 3,  0.888408,   -6.4700,    44
10V1,   lig278, 2,  0.915932,   -6.6600,    35
10V1,   lig12,  1,  0.922741,   -9.3600,    19
10V1,   lig12,  8,  0.934144,   -7.4600,    24
10V1,   lig40,  2,  0.949955,   -5.9000,    34
10V1,   lig800, 5,  0.964194,   -5.9200,    30
10V1,   lig868, 2,  0.966243,   -6.9100,    20
10V1,   lig12,  2,  0.972575,   -8.3000,    10
10V1,   lig619, 6,  0.979168,   -8.1600,    9
10V1,   lig619, 4,  0.986202,   -8.7800,    5
10V1,   lig800, 2,  0.989599,   -6.2400,    20
10V1,   lig619, 1,  0.989725,   -9.2900,    3
10V1,   lig12,  7,  0.991535,   -7.5800,    9
10V2,   lig40,  1,  0.525767,   -6.4600,    146
10V2,   lig211, 2,  0.744702,   -6.8200,    78
10V2,   lig278, 1,  0.749015,   -7.0900,    74
10V2,   lig868, 1,  0.772025,   -7.3100,    66
10V2,   lig211, 1,  0.799829,   -6.8700,    63
10V2,   lig12,  1,  0.899345,   -9.1600,    25
10V2,   lig12,  4,  0.899606,   -7.5500,    32
10V2,   lig868, 3,  0.903364,   -6.4800,    40
10V2,   lig278, 3,  0.913145,   -6.6300,    36
10V2,   lig800, 5,  0.94576,    -5.9100,    35
```

Comment: This may be shortened to `awk '(!_[$0]++)' input` . This would remove *all* duplicate lines ( both header or non header).

Comment: @PrabhjotSingh never name a variable `_` as that removes absolutely ALL information about what that variable represents, it's orders of magnitude worse than even using single character variable names as those usually tell you something. In this case the idiomatic name for the array used to distinguish first vs subsequent occurrences of it's index is `seen[]` as Praveen used. It should be written just `awk '!seen[$0]++'` as you suggest of course.

Comment: but as you correctly point out this approach will remove all duplicate lines, not just the header line, and so it shouldn't be used.